# Is it possible to encrypt the message using "x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305" algo on solidity?

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to encrypt the message using "x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305" algo on solidity ?

Comment: At this moment encryption algorithm are too complex to run on an EVM. Perhaps is some L2 chain as precompiled contract.